# The behavior of string.split for short strings when maxsplit is supplied

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, split

I recently ran across some intriguing behavior of the string.split method in python2.7, particularly with respect to short stings (less than around 25 chars, see below), that involves contrasting the behavior of:

```
# Without maxplsit
my_string.split('A')
```

to

```
# With maxsplit=1
my_string.split('A', 1)
```

The second method is actually slower for short strings, and I'm quite curious as to why.

### The Test

This first came about from a small call to timeit that my co-worker discovered:

```
# Without maxsplit
$ python -m timeit -s "json_line='a|b|c'" "part_one='|'.split(json_line)[0]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.274 usec per loop
# With maxsplit
$ python -m timeit -s "json_line='a|b|c'" "part_one='|'.split(json_line,1)[0]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.461 usec per loop
```

I thought this was certainly curious, so I put together a more detailed test.  First I wrote the following small function that generates random strings of a specified length consisting of the first ten capital letters:

```
from random import choice

# 'A' through 'J'
choices = map(chr, range(65, 75))

def make_random_string(length):
    return ''.join(choice(choices) for i in xrange(length))
```

Then I wrote a couple tester functions to repeatedly split and time randomly generated strings of a specified length:

```
from timeit import timeit

def time_split_of_size(str_length, n_strs_to_split):
    times = []
    data = [make_random_string(str_length) for i in xrange(n_strs_to_split)]
    for s in data:
        t = timeit("'{s}'.split('A')".format(s=s),
                   setup="from __main__ import make_random_string",
                   number=1000)
        times.append(t)
    return times

def time_split_of_size_with_maxcount(str_length, n_strs_to_split):
    times = []
    data = [make_random_string(str_length) for i in xrange(n_strs_to_split)]
    for s in data:
        t = timeit("'{s}'.split('A', 1)".format(s=s),
                   setup="from __main__ import make_random_string",
                   number=1000)
        times.append(t)
    return times
```

I then ran these testing methods over strings of varying sizes:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict({})
for str_length in xrange(10, 10*1000, 25):
    no_maxcount = mean(time_split_of_size(str_length, 20))
    with_maxcount = mean(time_split_of_size_with_maxcount(str_length, 20))
    d[str_length] = [no_maxcount, with_maxcount]
```

This gives you the behavior you would expect, O(1) for the method with maxsplit=1 and O(n) for splitting all the way.  Here's a plot of the time by the length of the string, the barely visible green curve is with `maxsplit=1` and the blue curve is without:

[image: StringSplitTiming]

None the less, the behavior my co-worker discovered for small stings is real.  Here's some code that times many splits of short stings:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict({})
for str_length in xrange(1, 50, 2):
    no_maxcount = mean(time_split_of_size(str_length, 500))
    with_maxcount = mean(time_split_of_size_with_maxcount(str_length, 500))
    d[str_length] = [no_maxcount, with_maxcount]
```

With the following results:

[image: StringSplitShortString]

It seems like there is some overhead for strings less than 25 or so characters in length.  The shape of the green curve is also quite curious, how it increases parallel to the blue before leveling off permenantly.

I took a look at the source code, which you may find here:

[stringobject.c](https://github.com/certik/python-2.7/blob/master/Objects/stringobject.c) (line 1449)
[stringlib/split.h](https://github.com/certik/python-2.7/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/split.h) (line 105)

but nothing obvious jumped out at me.

Any idea what is causing the overhead when maxsplit is passed for the short strings?

Comment: How fast is it when you pass `maxsplit=-1`, i.e., the default value, but passed explicitly?

Comment: For future reference, if you click on the line numbers at GitHub, you can get a link directly to that line (or you can just manually add `#L105` to the end of the URL).

Comment: One possible difference: for -1, `PREALLOC_SIZE` will allocate a list with room for 12 elements. You'd think that would be more expensive than pre-allocating only 2 elements… but maybe that 12-element-list size is something your freelist is just chock full of, because Python makes a similar assumption in other places? One way to test that is to pass `12` and see if it does the same thing as `-1` or the default.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Ahh!  I should have thought of that test!  That lowers the green curve uniformly in the y direction, and the maxplit is no longer slower.  Very nice.  The shape is still the same though, with the ramp up.  I suspect that's probably due to the expected number of chars to split at being less than one for short stings, but I think i needed to get unstuck from the other issue to realize that!  Thanks!

Comment: If that's true, and assuming nothing is wrong with your tests, it sounds like what you're measuring is the overhead of not finding a default-valued arg, vs. finding one and converting it from PyObject to long, in the [`PyArg_ParseTuple`](https://github.com/certik/python-2.7/blob/master/Objects/stringobject.c#L1456) function. Which seems like it should go the opposite way, and also seems like it shouldn't matter enough to affect the measurements.

Comment: @abarnert I had also made the assumption that parsing the default argument would be inconsequential compared to searching the string, and allocating and returning the answer.

Comment: One more thing: can you post your platform, Python, etc. details? I measure a crossover at almost exactly the same place, and if our systems are very different, that would make it more significant. (Mac, 10.10.4, i7, Apple Python 2.7.6 64-bit.)

Comment: @abarnert Mac, 10.9.5 Anaconda Python 2.7.6 64-bit.  Very close.

Comment: OK, now I have to test against 3.4 and see if it's the same (both with `str` and with `bytes`).

Comment: 2.7 `str`: crossover at 25. 2.7 `unicode`: 23. 3.4 `bytes`: 25 3.4 `str`: 21. So, basically no chance from 2.7 to 3.4, and tiny change between unicode and bytes.

Comment: OK, I'm pretty sure the difference is that executing the extra bytecode to push the const onto the stack; I'm just trying to figure out how to prove it…

Comment: I'm trying to think of another example of a builtin function that takes an optional argument where constant folding or interning won't get in the way (unlike, say, `int('5')` vs. `int('5', 10)` or `int()` vs. `int(0)`, where the first run always takes 12x as long as subsequent runs…).

Comment: @abarnert list.pop has an optional single argument...

Comment: @MatthewDrury: Good call; let me test that. But actually, `int(0)` isn't a problem in 2.7, only in 3.3+…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference actually has nothing to do with what's going on inside `string_split`. In fact, the time spent inside that function is always slightly longer for default split than for `maxsplit=1`, even if there are no splits to be done. And it's not the `PyArg_ParseTuple` difference (the best report I can get without instrumenting the interpreter says it takes 0ns either way, so whatever difference there is, it's not going to matter).

The difference is that it takes an extra bytecode to pass an extra parameter.

As [Stefan Pochmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672429/stefan-pochmann) suggested, you can tell this by testing with an explicit `maxsplit=-1`:

```
In [212]: %timeit ''.split('|')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 267 ns per loop
In [213]: %timeit ''.split('|', 1)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 303 ns per loop
In [214]: %timeit ''.split('|', -1)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 307 ns per loop
```

So even in this minimal example, the `-1` is slightly slower than the `1`. But we're talking about 4ns of extra work. (I'm pretty sure this 4ns is because of [preallocating a list of size 12 instead of size 2](https://github.com/certik/python-2.7/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/split.h#L10), but I don't want to run through a profiler just to make sure.)

Meanwhile, an NOP bytecode takes 32ns to evaluate on my system (from another answer I'm still trying to find…). I can't imagine that `LOAD_CONST` is faster than `NOP`.

So, until you're doing enough work to overwhelm that 32ns+, not passing a maxsplit argument will save you time.

In case it isn't obvious, here's the disassembly for the two cases:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('')
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (split)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('|')
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 RETURN_VALUE

  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('')
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (split)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('|')
              9 LOAD_CONST               3 (-1)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

For similar examples:

```
In [217]: %timeit int()
10000000 loops, best of 3: 94 ns per loop
In [218]: %timeit int(0)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 134 ns per loop
In [235]: %timeit [0].pop()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 229 ns per loop
In [236]: %timeit [0].pop(0)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 270 ns per loop
```

So the `LOAD_CONST` takes about 40ns in both these cases, just like passing `-1` instead of no argument for `split`.

Python 3.4 is a little harder to test, because it caches some things that 2.7 doesn't, but it looks like it's about 33ns to pass an extra argument—or 533ns if it's a keyword argument. So, if you need to split tiny strings a billion times in Python 3, use `s.split('|', 10)`, not `s.split('|', maxsplit=10)`.

Answer (score 0):

the proper initial test (original test had `json_line and` '|' mixed up)

```
python -m timeit -s "json_line='a|b|c'" "part_one=json_line.split('|')[0]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.239 usec per loop
python -m timeit -s "json_line='a|b|c'" "part_one=json_line.split('|',1)[0]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.267 usec per loop
```

The time difference is smaller.

Comment: You're right.  I'd copied that from my co-workers email.  Should I edit to fix it?